# Scala Spark - use Section sign as delimiter when writing to a CSV file

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

In short, using the section sign character `§` as a delimiter breaks the resulting CSV file in unexpected ways when trying to write a DataFrame.

I load the csv using the function:

```
def load(spark: SparkSession, path: String): DataFrame = {
    println(f"Loading $path to a DataFrame.")

    spark.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv(path)
}
```

After loading, I preclear ALL special characters from all of the columns of the DataFrame:

```
private def preClearData(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val dfCleaned = df.columns.foldLeft(df) { (memoDF, colName) =>
        memoDF.withColumn(colName, regexp_replace(df.col(colName), "[^ -~]", ""))
    }
    dfCleaned
}
```

After doing some work on the DataFrame, I have to save it as a CSV file using the section sign as a delimiter. I have the following function for saving to CSV:

```
def saveToCsv(df: DataFrame, fileName: String, delimiter: String = ","): Unit = {
    println(f"Writing $df to a file = $outputPath" + fileName)

    df
      .coalesce(1)
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", delimiter)
      .option("escape", "")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .csv(outputPath)

    handleCreatedOutput(fileName)
}
```

However, when I use the section sign as a delimiter, the resulting CSV file is nonsense. I have tried multiple regexes, including using `\u00A7` instead of `§`, but nothing seems to work. Strangely, if I use `,` as the delimiter, the resulting CSV file contains no special characters. The input file is encoded in UTF-8.

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which Spark version do you use? I have tested the delimiter "§" with 3.3.0 and it worked fine. This there probably a bug inside of `handleCreatedOutput`?

Comment: @werner I am using Spark version 2.4.8. with Scala version 2.15.2. The function `handleCreatedOutput` just renames the created CSV file from the `part-<part-00000>` format. I am very new to Spark and I couldn't figure out how to make the `df.write()` create the CSV with the passed name, so I created that helper function and do it manually.